# Playing background movie while animation in blender

Tags: animation, blender

I have made an animation in Blender showing an aircraft flying for about 900 frames. I would like the background to be something like clouds but with changing the color of the sky from light blue to dark blue ( like each frame to make the blue color little darker )

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Simple, move the timeline to the first frame

[image]

hold your mouse over the sky colour you want to animate, and press 'i' on your keyboard (or right click and click on 'insert keyframe')

[image]

move the timeline to the end frame, or whatever frame you want the transition to end on

[image]

Change the horizon colour to what you want it to end on, and press 'i' on your keyboard (or right click and click on 'insert keyframe')

[image]

Try it!

Comment: ye that prob would work with choosing color, but is there a way to move picture i uploaded?